# Method Range of Obeject_Worksheet killing code - what's wrong?

Tags: vba

I'm trying to write some VBA that:

1. Searches a column in one worksheet ("2013-2018 Combined") to find the max value
2. Pastes that value + 1 to the bottom row in another worksheet

I'm getting errors when trying to define U below. Would appreciate some help as I've tried to debug it with no result.

**Error: 1004 - Method 'Range of Object'_Worksheet failed**

```
Dim wscombined As Worksheet
Dim wspsimp As Worksheet
Dim u As Integer

Set wscombined = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2013-2018 Combined")
Set wspsimp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pipeline simplified")
u = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(wscombined.Range("A7:A"))


LastRowU = wspsimp.Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

LastRowU.Offset(0, -8).Select

 '  Increment cell value by 1
   ActiveCell.Value = u + 1
```

Comment: This is not valid syntax `Range("A7:A")` - A7 to where?

Comment: `LastRowU.Offset(0, -8).Value = u + 1`

Comment: SJR - I've tried to change it to Range ("A:A") or ("A7:A50") and different problem on LastRowU.Offset  - "Object Required"

Comment: Ah yes, `LastRowU` is a number so is not a valid range and Offset requires a range. So you would need something like `cells(LastRowU,1).offset(,-8).value=u+1`.

Comment: Nope - Error 1004. Application or Object defined error

Comment: Well you can't go back 8 columns from A so change the column reference to whatever is required.

Comment: `cells(LastRowU,"J").offset(,-8).value=u+1` ???

Comment: My bad - you're right. Brain frazzled today. Working well now. Thanks for your help!